# How to Add Class to Bootstrap Thumbnails on Slider Change

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can you please take a look at [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/wLqXF/) and let me know let me know how I can add the class .highlight either on gallery carousel-control clicks to the thumbs?

As you can see from the code I am using following code to highlight the selected thumbs:

```
var classHighlight = 'highlight';
var $thumbs = $('.thumbnail').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$thumbs.removeClass(classHighlight);
$(this).addClass(classHighlight);
});
```

well, I am not sure that is correct way but it is working for me! but as I said this is working on clicking on .thumbnail but what I need is adding the class to thumbnails on sliding event. I already add this CSS to my code but it is not working!

```
.thumbnail:active{
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px;
  border-color:gery;
  }
```

Thanks for you time and comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the on slide function to do that (added the 2 bottom lines):

> ```
>    // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
>     $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
>             var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
>             $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
>         $('#slider-thumbs > div > ul > li > a').removeClass('highlight');
>         $('#carousel-selector-'+id).addClass('highlight');
>     });
> ```

To select the first thumbnail on page load add this line on top, after the initialization of carousel:

> ```
>    $('#carousel-selector-0').addClass('highlight');
> ```

Fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wLqXF/4/)